# How to place a marker on top of image with the marker's position given with respect to the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put a marker on top of a map based on where the user specifies.

I have it working using the absolute position and the coordinates with respect to the window, but if something on the page changes size it will shift the image but not the marker coordinates.

I want to have the marker coordinates with respect to the position of the image, not the window. I'm new to HTML and JavaScript, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8S96W/1/)

HTML

```
<form name="parts">
    <input type="text" name="item" size="10"> 
</form>

<input type="button" onclick="get_location();" value="Search">

<img src="http://www.shankerhotel.com.np/images/google_map.png" id="marker" width="50px" height="50px" style="display: none; position: absolute" />

<img src="http://www.outline-world-map.com/map-images-original/outline-world-map-blank-white-b3b.png" width="800" height="400" id="map"  />
```

JavaScript

```
function get_location() {
    var location = document.forms['parts']['item'].value;

    if (location == "England")     
         coordinates = [310,80];
    else if( location == "Canada") 
         coordinates = [100,80];
    else 
         alert("Not found");

    document.getElementById('map').onload = put_marker(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);

}

function put_marker(from_left, from_top) {
    with(document.getElementById('marker')) {
        style.left = from_left + "px";
        style.top = from_top + "px";
        style.display = "block";
    }
};
```

Comment: Put the image and the markers into a common container element, and position in relation to that container element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Just wrap the content into some "position: relative" div. The marker image would be positioned inside this container no matter where it moves:

```
<div id="container" style="position: relative;">

  <img src="http://www.shankerhotel.com.np/images/google_map.png" id="marker" width="50px" height="50px" style="display: none; position: absolute" />

  <img src="http://www.outline-world-map.com/map-images-original/outline-world-map-blank-white-b3b.png" width="800" height="400" id="map"  />

</div>
```

Comment: And you'll have to update the coordinates to match just the image, so it does not include height of the form etc.

Comment: Do you know how to get it to center on the screen? If I try to make that `div` `align="center"`, the marker will no longer move horizontally relative to the map, it will move horizontally relative to the edge.

Comment: Look at this updated fiddle, it should handle it. You need to specify the DIV's width to fit the image. Otherwise it will stretch to the width of parent element (body in your case)

http://jsfiddle.net/8S96W/6/